# Building a adding products with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

the output it generating is not correct can someone help me fix it.

it seems the error is in javascript, i think it logic error and been racking my head nothing pls help

```js
 var total = document.getElementById('total');
 var price = document.getElementById('price').value
 var price2 = document.getElementById('price2').value;
 var i =0;

 var totalPrice =0;
function add(){

 i++
 total.innerHTML = i * price;


}

function add2(){
 
 i++
 total.innerHTML =i * price2 ;

}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="total pull-right" id="total" >Total Price: </li>
</ul>

      <div class="product_box ">
      
        <h3 id="name">Blackberry</h3>
        50000 <input type="number" name="" id="price" value="50000">
        <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add()">ADD TO CART</button>
      </div>
    
      <div class="product_box">

        <h3 id="name">IPHONE 3</h3>
        100000 <input type="number" name="" id="price2" value="100000">
        <button class="AddtoCart" onclick="add2()">ADD TO CART</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You completely neglect to describe to us what this code is supposed to do in the first place. Don’t let people try and guess that - _explain it!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to find the total amount then you need to add your price with the totalPrice (variable) on each each.see the following script.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var total = document.getElementById('total');
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value
    var price2 = document.getElementById('price2').value;
    var i =0; 

    var totalPrice =0;

function add(){  
    totalPrice= Number(totalPrice)+Number(price) ;
    total.innerHTML = totalPrice; 
}


function add2(){ 
    totalPrice= Number(totalPrice )+Number(price2);
    total.innerHTML =totalPrice;

}

 </script>
```